# Nested Logic Gates

Tags: macros, recursion

I am trying to get a nand gate to work like the one mentioned in [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2012/04/24/latex-is-more-powerful-than-you-think.html) article, and it takes issue with the ifnum being fed a single integer rather than a pair of integers with an equals. When I fix that, I come up with code that looks something like this:

```
 \newcommand{\nand}[2]{
 \count0=#1
 \count1=#2
 \ifnum \count0=\count1 \ifnum \count0=1 0\else 1 \fi \else 1 \fi
 }
```

and at first seems to work fine, i.e. when I do `\nand{1}{1}` I get `0`. However, when I try `\nand{\nand{1}{1}}{1}` I get `=1 0 0`. This does not seem to make any sense. Do I need to use a different keyword to force LaTeX to use the result of the command? What is causing this not to output `1`?

Comment: First of all, \count0 is reserved for the page counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignments within the macro make it not expandable, and therefore you cannot nest it within other macros. If you go without the assignment, then you can nest them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nand}[2]{%
  \ifnum #1=#2 \ifnum #1=1 0\else 1 \fi \else 1 \fi
}

\begin{document}

\verb|\nand{0}{0}|: \nand{0}{0}% 1

\verb|\nand{0}{1}|: \nand{0}{1}% 1

\verb|\nand{1}{0}|: \nand{1}{0}% 1

\verb|\nand{1}{1}|: \nand{1}{1}% 0

\bigskip

\verb|\nand{\nand{0}{0}}{0}|: \nand{\nand{0}{0}}{0}% \nand{1}{0} = 1

\verb|\nand{\nand{0}{1}}{0}|: \nand{\nand{0}{1}}{0}% \nand{1}{0} = 1

\verb|\nand{\nand{1}{0}}{0}|: \nand{\nand{1}{0}}{0}% \nand{1}{0} = 1

\verb|\nand{\nand{1}{1}}{0}|: \nand{\nand{1}{1}}{0}% \nand{0}{0} = 1

\verb|\nand{\nand{0}{0}}{1}|: \nand{\nand{0}{0}}{1}% \nand{1}{1} = 0

\verb|\nand{\nand{0}{1}}{1}|: \nand{\nand{0}{1}}{1}% \nand{1}{1} = 0

\verb|\nand{\nand{1}{0}}{1}|: \nand{\nand{1}{0}}{1}% \nand{1}{1} = 0

\verb|\nand{\nand{1}{1}}{1}|: \nand{\nand{1}{1}}{1}% \nand{0}{1} = 1


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It works if you write it this way:

```
\newcommand\nand[2]{
    \ifnum #1=#2 \ifnum #1=1 0 \else 1 \fi \else 1 \fi
}
```

Comment: Interesting, any idea why?

Comment: I think, from Werner's explanation, that by having `\counter1` and `\counter2` defined/called within the macro, `\counter1` ends up being nested inside itself.